# i want to merge array having one unique value like id and other are different values and key also

Tags: php, arrays

```
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [billing_first_name] => pp
            [user_id] => 1
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [billing_last_name] => pp
            [user_id] => 1
        )
        [2] => Array(
            [billing_city] => Nagpur
            [user_id] => 1
        )
        [3] => Array(
            [billing_first_name] => gaurav
            [user_id] => 6
        )
        [4] => Array(
            [billing_last_name] => bokade
            [user_id] => 6
        )
    )
```

and I want Result As :

```
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [user_id] => 1
            [billing_first_name] => pp
            [billing_last_name] => pp
            [billing_city] => Nagpur
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [user_id] => 6
            [billing_first_name] => gaurav
            [billing_last_name] => bokade
            [billing_city] => 
        )
    )
```

Comment: you should also format the result you want, so that it is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                array('billing_first_name' => 'pp','user_id' => 1),
                array('billing_last_name' => 'pp','user_id' => 1),
                array('billing_city' => 'Nagpur','user_id' => 1),
                array('billing_first_name' => 'gaurav','user_id' => 6),
                array('billing_last_name' => 'bokade','user_id' => 6)
            );

    foreach($array as $r){
        foreach($r as $key => $s){
            $new[$r['user_id']][$key] = $s;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
?>
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [billing_first_name] => pp
            [user_id] => 1
            [billing_last_name] => pp
            [billing_city] => Nagpur
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [billing_first_name] => gaurav
            [user_id] => 6
            [billing_last_name] => bokade
        )

)
```

Comment: billing_city is necessary in  second array...?